# First Isomorphism Theorem for Bilinear Maps

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Let $U,V,W$ be three vector spaces over the same field. Let 
$$\phi:U\times V\to W$$
be a bilinear map. That is, for every $u\in U$ the map
$$\phi_u : V\to W$$
$$v \mapsto \phi(u,v)$$
is linear. Likewise for every $v$ in $V$, the map
$$\phi_v : U\to W$$
$$u \mapsto \phi(u,v)$$
is linear. Then is there a first isomorphism theorem known is this situation. The obvious guess would be that
$$Im(\phi) \cong U\times V / \ker\phi.$$
Although I am having trouble proving it (and am not completely convinced it is true). Is there such a theorem known? Something that relates the image of $\phi$ with its kernel? Any reference or solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The obvious guess is false. The image of a bilinear map needs not be a vector subspace of $W$. There are some theorems stating isomorphisms around bilinear maps (particularly, bilinear form), but none of the kind you're looking for.

Comment: What is the kernel of a biliniear, not necessrily linear map?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Do you know what these theorems are. I am generally interested in relating the image of a bilinear map with its preimage so anything would be helpful.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I guess the kernel would be the preimage of the zero vector. Although, if you know of a different notion of a kernel of a bilinear map that would lend itself to some kind of first isomorphism theorem I would be glad to hear of it.

Comment: @Mastrel: As I said, the image of a bilinear map is usually not a vector subspace (it is an algebraic variety, and I'm not sure what its properties are). For example, the pure tensors in a tensor product are the image of a bilinear map. A while ago I have written up some basic facts about bilinear forms in [*A note on bilinear forms*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/bilf.pdf), before realizing that most of them had rather trivial proofs. Some of them extend to bilinear maps (i.e., the target doesn't have to be the base field), but none of them characterizes the image.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Is it known that the image can never be characterized by the pre-image and kernel (or some other kernel-like object)?

Comment: Depends on how liberally you understand the notion of a "kernel-like object". Any bilinear map $\phi : U \times V \to W$ gives rise to a linear map $\Phi : U \otimes V \to W$. The image of $\phi$ is the image of the set $T$ of all pure tensors in $U \otimes V$ under $\Phi$. This image can be characterized as the quotient of the set $T$ modulo the equivalence relation under which two pure tensors are equivalent if and only if their images under $\Phi$ are equal. (This is a quotient of sets, and maybe of algebraic varieties in an appropriate sense.) If you regard ...

Comment: ... the equivalence relation as a "kernel-like object", then yes, it thus characterizes the image of $\phi$. But this is not as useful as the first isomorphism theorem for linear maps.