# How to show that the images of pairs of basis elements are a basis of $Im\phi$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\phi$ be a bilinear map on a vector space $V$ to some space $W$that is injective.

How to show that the elements $\phi(e_i,e_j)$ form a linearly independant family ? The $e_i$ are a basis of $V$

Comment: Can you provide some context on this question? Is it for homework?

Comment: No I saw the definition of tensor product space in terms of its naturel property, and this question appeared in my mid to justify it

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: @Alan I really can't make progress, intuitively there is no way to express one of those  ϕ(ei,ej) in terms of the others using only the definition of a bilinear application but it's not a proof

Comment: i think you can use the homomorphism theorem and injectivity to get a contradiction if your family is dependent. i'm supposing the vector spaces are finite dimensional.

Comment: according to the comments in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2360410/first-isomorphism-theorem-for-bilinear-maps) question, it doesn't work.

Comment: So the image of a bilinear map would not necessarily be a vector subspace of W ? N.B. I say phi is injective, but this excludes the cases phi(a,b)=phi(ak,b/k) so phi(a,b)=phi(c,d) iff c=ka and d=1/kb.

Comment: @eternalstudent Perhaps instead of saying that $\phi$ is "injective" (which as you note is not quite correct), we should say that $\phi$ induces an injective (linear) map over the [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Universal_property) $V \otimes V$